# How to concatenate two functions on the same line?

Tags: python

```
def headName():
    print (Name[0].upper())
def tailName():
    print (Name[1:].lower())

Name = input("Please enter a name ")
headName()
tailName()
```

That's my code; I want to know how to concatinate headName() and tailName(), so that they're on the same line. Thanks

Comment: I assume you mean you want to get the *output* of `headName` and `tailName` on the same line?

Comment: What do you mean: do you want to define two functions on the same line? Do you want each function definition to only take up one line?

Comment: Yes BrenBarn. It keeps putting it on two lines

Comment: So, it's not to do with functions, it's to do with output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that without rewriting the functions.  The newline is added by `print`.  Since you call `print` inside the functions, nothing you do outside the function can undo the newline that was already added inside.

A better idea is to have your functions *return* the values, and then do the printing outside:

```
def headName():
    return Name[0].upper()
def tailName():
    return Name[1:].lower()

Name = input("Please enter a name ")
print(headName(), tailName(), sep="")
```

Incidentally, what you are doing can also be accomplished directly with `Name.title()`.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks a lot. I have a question about your solution in order to better understand it; what does the, 'sep=" ")' mean? I haven't learnt about this yet, so am unsure WHY it works

Comment: @TheWhiteWolf: By default, `print` inserts a space between each pair of things you print on the same line.  Setting `sep` to the empty string prevents it from doing that, so that you get, e.g., `"Somedude"` instead of `"S omedude"`.  See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

To print on the same line call them in one `print` statement, something like:

```
print(headName(), ' ', tailName())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use string formatting, which in case that you wanted to customize further the output would give you more control over the outcome:

```
def headName():
    return Name[0].upper()
def tailName():
    return Name[1:].lower()

Name = input("Please enter a name ")
print('{}{}'.format(headName(), tailName()))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
def headName():
    print ((Name[0].upper()), end="")
```

This will cause your print function to end with nothing, instead of ending with a newline (default).

For more information: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html